# Can I use an IF...ELSE statement to set a field? (T-SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I currently have a query that sets the value of a field to '1' if two values match from two fields in two different tables using an INNER JOIN. It currently is as such:

```
UPDATE [ARCSEQP]
SET [isKid] = 1
FROM [ARCSITE]
INNER JOIN [ARCSEQP]
ON [ARCSITE].[CSI_SVID] = [ARCSEQP].[SERVID]
```

This works perfectly. However, I also want to set [isKid] to 0 if the values from the join do not match. I can do this by just writing a separate update statement but I was wondering if it were possible to do this using some sort of IF...ELSE statement. This may not be the best way of doing it but it seems more efficient than two separate update statements. If I'm wrong, go a head and correct me.

Answer (score 5):

use `LEFT JOIN` and a `CASE` statement.

```
UPDATE  [ARCSEQP]
SET     [isKid] = CASE WHEN [ARCSEQP].[SERVID] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
FROM    [ARCSITE]
        LEFT JOIN [ARCSEQP]
            ON [ARCSITE].[CSI_SVID] = [ARCSEQP].[SERVID]
```